# Access to a specific file location (c:/folder/file) in an Azure website

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, filepath, azure-web-roles

A company provides me a .dll with many files.
The dll access to files using this kind of path "`C:/folder/file.config`".
I'm working on IIS 8 over a dedicated server BUT I would like to migrate the project on Windows Azure.

I know that Windows Azure provides Virtual Machines, But I wouldn't use it just for this need.

In my dream, I would like to use a web site linked to an Azure Storage and the dll which is located on the web site could access to its "`C:/folder/file.config`".

Could Windows Azure has a storage which support basic path ? ("`C:/folder/file.config`")
How could I solved this problem without using a Virtual Machine ?

Comment: Could you change that `c:/folder/file.config` path? Is it loaded from some configuration file?

Comment: I can't change this path, They just provide me the .dll and the path is written directly in their code. Unfortunately, I don't have access to their code.

Comment: You already tagged it with `azure-web-roles`, then you don't have to go all the way to a VM Role, you can use WebRole as well.

Comment: Could you give me more description of how could I do it through WebRoles please ? Is the path "C:/folder/file.config" is managed natively with Web Roles ?

Comment: First you include the `file.config` as part of your Role-Content (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/philliphoff/archive/2012/06/08/add-files-to-your-windows-azure-package-using-role-content-folders.aspx) Then you use a Startup-Task (msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg456327.aspx‎
) Or WebRole.cs (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimoneil/archive/2010/07/23/azure-home-part-2-webrole-implementation.aspx?Redirected=true) to copy the file to your desired location.

Answer (score 3):

You need to exercise caution before moving onto this Azure solution for the following reasons:

1. Azure Web Roles will have read/write access only to the Root Website folder and sub-folders. Not to any other.
2. Also, even if you manage to get permissions to the expected folder, remember that the instance can be recycled anytime. Meaning you need to repeat your startup task of creating the folder structure and putting the file there, setting up permissions etc.
3. And finally, the web instances are independent of each other with their own copies of the config file. So you need to take care of any sync issues. (just read-only doesn't pose a problem)
4. Filesystem access requires a bunch of csdef configurations as well along with elevated tasks.

http://blog.codingoutloud.com/2011/06/12/azure-faq-can-i-write-to-the-file-system-on-windows-azure/

Comment: The file will be set as Read Only

Comment: Is it a kind of mapping c:/folder/file => /Root/folder/file ?

Comment: Actually it's much simpler than you portray it to be in your answer. 1) from elevated startup tasks, you can write to the C: drive. This is not difficult at all. 2) By definition, the startup task is run at boot time, every time. Just create a simple script to copy the DLL, either from the deployment package itself, or from blob storage. 4) Not sure what you mean by *bunch of csdef configurations*. Create a `<Startup>` element inside the role, then add `<Task executionContext="elevated" commandLine="..." />`.

Answer (score 1):

In Azure Websites your website located here :

```
d:\home\site\wwwroot
```

which actually mapping for :

```
C:\DWASFiles\Sites\[your website name]
```

you can't access any parent folder above that folder in C: partition in Azure Websites

Comment: is it the same limitation with the cloud services ?

Comment: Do you have any documentation about this please ?

Comment: I've no documentation for that. you can test by yourself [your-website].scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole. by the way , you can access any files in D: partition, so you can upload your configuration files into d:\folder\file.config , then from your code you can access this file by System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"d:\folder\file.config"); but you can't do his with C: partition

Comment: you can upload your files using SCM, or by changing the build output path for this files to d:\folder\file.config. I recommend to make its path under d:\home\site\wwwroot , or C:\DWASFiles\Sites\[your-site-name]\VirtualDirectory0\site\wwwroot , then you can access it from your code

Comment: in the cloud services you have no limitation, because its like you own the server its like VM