# Get FileInfo from remote path

Tags: c#, azure, model-view-controller, fileinfo

I have some files on Azure Storage eg
http://mywebsite.blob.core.windows.net/scans/1d251700-5457-49c6-abec-c70fa37f77dd.png
I am using MVC app as my api to process files etc.
To do what I want I need to create FileInfo object from the image.

Is it possible somehow using path as above?

Comment: I am quite convinced that is impossible. But I finally found work around thanks to user ammaroff and his comment on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22956786/access-to-a-specific-file-location-c-folder-file-in-an-azure-website
([your-website].scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole)
Silly mistake but folder I was trying to save file to was empty when I deployed solution to Azure so it was simply not there.
Lucky I found it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to utilise the Azure Storage SDK in your application.  This can be [installed via nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/) in Visual Studio.  Once you have this installed you need to setup an access key to the blob storage location(s) you are reading and writing from and use the Storage client. There is a great [how-to on the Azure documentation site](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/).

Comment: Thank you for that answer. I think I was misunderstood...
I also think that link with Azure documentation is very helpful.

Comment: Thank you for that answer. I think I was misunderstood...
Azure documentation is very helpful alright.
I am able to save file on Azure Storage and store its url.
I need the FileInfo of the image tho.
(I think) FileInfo constructor takes a string with physical path eg @"C:\\image.jpg" but I have virtrual path eg "http://myweb.com/images/image.jpg"
Is it possible to get around that? 
I was trying to create and save image directly into folder of MVC application which worked locally but on Server it was returning 500 
maybe I have no permission or I was doing it wrong.
Suggestions are welcome

Comment: Persistent local file storage in Azure (or any cloud really) is generally a bad idea because your instance may be re-provisioned at any time and any local uploads would be lost.  As you suggested you are probably getting problems due to local filesystem security on your host. Websites, Web Roles (Cloud Services) and Virtual Machines have differeing levels of security but typically anything mapping to a path under "~/" should be accessible. Put your files temporarily there and extract the FileInfo you need, but store the file in Blob Storage.